# How to fix the error when only some data is displayed using web API on Xamarin Android

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, api, xamarin.android, getmethod

I created a personal info page to display all the data according to specific username entered. Unfortunately, the edit text didn't display all the data from the SQL Server. It only shows 2/8 data. I'm using a WEB API to retrieve the data and the data is stored in SQL Server. Can you help me to fix this problem please!!

I obtained this code from a website and i follow step by step according to the website. I've tried using Web services, it didn't work ass well.

**VehicleRecord.cs**

```
public class VehicleRecord
    {
        public string clFullName{ get; set; }
        public string clGender{ get; set; }
        public string clICNo { get; set; }
        public string clAddress { get; set; }
        public string clPhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string clEmail { get; set; }
        public string clUsername { get; set; }
        public string clPwd { get; set; }
        public string clVehicPlateNo { get; set; }
        public string clVehicModel { get; set; }
        public string clVehicCol { get; set; }
        public string clPaymentMethod { get; set; }

        public VehicleRecord()
        {
            this.clFullName = "";
            this.clGender = "";
            this.clICNo = "";
            this.clAddress = "";
            this.clPhoneNo = "";
            this.clEmail = "";
            this.clUsername = "";
            this.clPwd = "";
            this.clVehicPlateNo = "";
            this.clVehicModel = "";
            this.clVehicCol = "";
            this.clPaymentMethod = "";
        }
    }
```

**Service.cs**

```
public class Service
    {
        public static async Task<dynamic> getServiceData(string queryString)
        {
            dynamic acc = null;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

            if(response != null)
            {
                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                acc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            }

            return acc;
        }
    }
```

**Acc.cs**

```
 public class Acc
    {
        public static async Task<VehicleRecord> GetAcc(string username)
        {
            string queryString = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/PMSAPI1/api/users/" + username;
            dynamic results = await Service.getServiceData(queryString).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if(results != null)
            {
                VehicleRecord vehicleRecord = new VehicleRecord();
                vehicleRecord.clFullName = (string)results["clFullName"];
                vehicleRecord.clGender = (string)results["clGender"];
                vehicleRecord.clICNo = (string)results["clICNo"];
                vehicleRecord.clAddress = (string)results["clAddress"];
                vehicleRecord.clPhoneNo = (string)results["clPhoneNo"];
                vehicleRecord.clEmail = (string)results["clEmail"];
                vehicleRecord.clPwd = (string)results["clPwd"];
                vehicleRecord.clVehicPlateNo = (string)results["clVehicPlateNo"];
                vehicleRecord.clVehicModel = (string)results["clVehicModel"];
                vehicleRecord.clVehicCol = (string)results["clVehicCol"];
                vehicleRecord.clPaymentMethod = (string)results["clPaymentMethod"];
                return vehicleRecord;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**PersonalInfoActivity.cs**

```
private async void BtnGetAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditText username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Text))
            {
                VehicleRecord vehicleRecord = await Acc.GetAcc(username.Text);
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtFullName).Text = vehicleRecord.clFullName;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtGender).Text = vehicleRecord.clGender;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtIC).Text = vehicleRecord.clICNo;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAddress).Text = vehicleRecord.clAddress;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo).Text = vehicleRecord.clPhoneNo;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail).Text = vehicleRecord.clEmail;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPwd).Text = vehicleRecord.clPwd;
                FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPayMethod).Text = vehicleRecord.clPaymentMethod;
            }
        }
```

The expected output should display all the data according to the username entered, but the actual output only displayed 2/8 data.

The error that i get is **System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

[The output displayed on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFpsc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue starts at this line

```
vehicleRecord.clICNo = (string)results["clICNo"];
```

IMO results does not contains "clICNo". Check this by surrounding this line in try - catch block.

Comment: Is it because of the l look similar like i?? @Darko Martinovic

Comment: i've found the mistakes. I wrongly name the edit text. Btw thank you for helping me!!!!